# javascript get responsive div height for svg animation

Tags: javascript, svg, background

I found some JS that creates an animated svg page background.  I want to use it only inside a responsive DIV with class="workout".  I'm just learning JS and I can't figure out how to change this code to get the height of the DIV the svg is inside.  Since the DIV is full screen width I only need to get the height.  Here is the relative code:

```js
    var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
    svg.setAttribute('width',window.innerWidth);
    svg.setAttribute('height',window.innerHeight);
    document.querySelector('.workout').appendChild(svg);
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('workout')[0].clientHeight;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, George!  That helped me figure out what to do.  Here is the code that works:

```js
    var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
    var divHeight = document.getElementsByClassName('workout')[0].clientHeight;
    svg.setAttribute('width',window.innerWidth);
    svg.setAttribute('height',document.divHeight);
    document.querySelector('.workout').appendChild(svg);
```